# How to find a vector on a plane given the plane's equation, the normal, and a point on the plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

So I need to find a vector on a randomly given plane with a given normal and a point on the plane. I plan on doing this in C++ in runtime so unfortunately I don't think I can just find $X, Y,$ and $Z$ using Normal $N = \langle n_x, n_y, n_z \rangle$ and the point $P = (p_x, p_y, p_z)$ to get

$n_x \ X+n_y \ Y+n_z \ Z = n_x \ p_x + n_y \ p_y + n_z \ p_z$

and just plug numbers into $X, Y,$ and $Z$ until I have a vector.

Does anyone know how to get the $X, Y,$ and $Z$ of a vector in runtime?